# How can I add a point to the route created using nx.shortest_path?

Tags: python, graph, maps, networkx, folium

From a point(startPoint), I find the closest node(closestPoint) in the graph. Then create the shortest route to a random point(endPoint). Sometimes the route includes the startPoint sometimes not, depending on the closestNode. If it includes, I want the route to start with the startPoint and end with the endPoint. If it does not, I want it to start with closestPoint and end with endPoint. How can I do it?

I tried to append startNode to the route then plot it, didn't work.

```
G = ox.graph_from_point(startPoint, distance=distance)

nodes, _ = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)

tree = KDTree(nodes[['y', 'x']], metric='euclidean')
latlon = getLatLonFromPoint(aPoint)
node_idx = tree.query([latlon], k=1, return_distance=False)[0]

theNode = nodes.iloc[node_idx].index.values[0]
startNode = theNode

endNode = np.random.choice(G.nodes)

route = nx.shortest_path(G, startNode, endNode)

m = ox.plot_route_folium(G, route, route_color='green',popup_attribute='length')
display(m)
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You have a list of node IDs.  You've described the process: if `StartPoint` exists in the list, you slice off the portion of the list in front of that.

Comment: route includes nodes. startPoint does not have to be a node so it is not in the list.

Comment: Ah.  (1) Add `startPoint` to the graph, or (2) check whether `startPoint` is between `startNode` and the second point of the path.  If it is, then replace `startNode` with `startPoint`.

Comment: How can I check if it's in between?

Comment: Use the geometric definition of "between".